# Vue history mode for non SPA

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router

I'm working on a semi-SPA VUE- page.
By semi-SPA i mean that just a few parts of the page are SPA:s (using routing).
The problem is that it generates a #-sign in the URL and the customer really doesn't like that.
To get rid of it you can use history mode but from what I can find it's only possible in a "pure" SPA-solution since it need to point back to a starting point if it doesn't find the specific route.
Is it possible to remove the #-sign from the URL in this scenario?

Comment: did you found a solution ?